# How is Mn+7 in the Permanganate ion considered as momentarily reduced to +6 in LMCT?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, absorption

I saw this passage on a book and it says that Ligand to Metal Charge Transfer (LMCT) overpowers d-d transitions thus the permanganate ion has an intense purple color. However, it was mentioned that the Mn+7 ion was momentarily reduced to Mn+6 in the charge transfer, how is that?

[image]